# SharePoint Version History Export

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export, version-history

I can't seem to find any other forms on Microsoft or here on StackExchange about version history exporting for 2016 versions of SharePoint. Anybody have any ideas to get a version history export on SharePoint 2016?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use CSOM C# code instead of powershell, you can try below code to get version history of file:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/mydocument.doc");
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();

ListItem currentItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
context.Load(currentItem);
context.ExecuteQuery();

FileVersionCollection versions = file.Versions;
context.Load(versions);
context.ExecuteQuery();

if (versions != null)
{
    foreach (FileVersion _version in versions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_version.Created);
        Console.WriteLine(_version.CheckInComment);
        Console.WriteLine(_version.CreatedBy);
        Console.WriteLine(_version.VersionLabel);
        Console.WriteLine(_version.IsCurrentVersion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following PowerShell script that working properly on 2013,  but I didn't try it on 2016, but it should be working !!

Meanwhile,If you faced any issue to run this script in SharePoint 2016 , you should have a look to [How to Adapt your older SharePoint PowerShell Scripts to Support SharePoint 2016](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=608)

```
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables
$WebURL="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Sales/"
$ListName ="Invoice"
$ReportFile = "D:\Invoice_VersionHistory.csv"
# *********************************************

#delete file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportFile)
 {
 Remove-Item $ReportFile
 }

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

 #Check if list exists
 if($List -ne $null)
 {
  #Get all list items
  $ItemsColl = $List.Items

  #Write Report Header
  Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value "Item ID, Version Lable, Created by, Created at, Title"

  #Loop through each item
  foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)
  {
   #Iterate each version
      foreach($version in $item.Versions)
       {
    #Get the version content
    $VersionData = "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title'])"
    #Write to report
    Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value $VersionData
   }
  }
 }
Write-Host "Version history has been exported successfully!"
```

Ref : [Export SharePoint List Item Version History to CSV](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/sharepoint-version-history-export-to-excel.html#ixzz4RKpLG3NV)

Comment: is there any solution for SP 2010 as well ?

Comment: this will also work for SharePoint 2010 :)